# Is Reaction commerce 2.0 (latest commit on repo) still compatible with 1.16.0 documentation when using legacy reaction?

Tags: javascript, meteor, plugins, reaction-commerce

When trying to integrate COD plugin to Reaction Commerce (https://github.com/reactioncommerce/payments-cod) we get this error

> While processing files with template-compiler (for target web.browser):
>   index.html:1: Cant' set DOCTYPE here. (Meteor sets  for you)

We are currently using Reaction Commerce 2.0 but using the classical UI (legacy)